# xcode 5 no sound from mp3 on iOS 6 or earlier

Tags: ios, avaudioplayer

The app plays some mp3 files and is working well on iOS 7, but on iOS 6 or earlier, the mp3 files are not played or at least I can hear nothing.

This is the code I use for playing mp3:

```
    fileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/puerta.m4a", [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath]]];

//Initialize the AVAudioPlayer.
self.audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:fileURL error:nil];

// Preloads the buffer and prepares the audio for playing.
[self.audioPlayer prepareToPlay];

self.audioPlayer.currentTime = 0;

[self.audioPlayer play];
```

Does anyone had a similar issue and how fixed it - Many thanks for help.

Comment: OK, I have found my issue. Very stupid. As the app was done early 2009, I used XIB. To update to latest version I decided to redo the app, with Storyboard. My mistake was to not copy the mp3 files into the app. As only linked, they are not available for the app, at least in iOS6, because in iOS7 they worked fine.